# Python, Linux, Tensorflow

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow

```
2021-10-12 22:05:52.734656: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-10-12 22:05:52.734672: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
2021-10-12 22:05:53.262948: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-10-12 22:05:53.262966: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2021-10-12 22:05:53.262978: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (excalibur): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2021-10-12 22:05:53.263135: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

У меня карта amd и linux, кто то знает что нужно сделать чтоб мне не выдавало страшные красные ошибки??7?

Comment: Удалите пакет `tensorflow-gpu`

Comment: Раздобудьте себе карточку nvidia.